# What's the equivalent object model to SiteData.EnumerateFolder in MOSS Web Service?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

There is a use in our project code in the SiteData WebService, for some reason that use is problematic and anyway it is code that runs on the **server**- therefore I look for object model equivalent for the EnumerateFolder method

Anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPList (amongst other classes) have a [RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder.aspx) property.
From that you can use [Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.files.aspx) to get a list of files. And [SubFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.subfolders.aspx) to get a collection of sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks, had it with GetItems and the appropriate SPQuery